# A question about the "stopping time with respect to a set" of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given a Markov chain with state space $\Omega$ and transition matrix $P$, and $A\subset \Omega$, define function$f(x)=\Bbb E _x(\tau_A)$, where $\tau_A$ is the "stopping time with respect to a set", meaning the first time the Markov chain reaches a state in $A$.

Obviously, $f(x)=0$ if $x\in A$.

The question is to show $f\left( x \right) = 1 + \mathop \sum \limits_{y \in {\rm{\Omega }}} P\left( {x,y} \right)f\left( y \right)$ for $x\notin A$.

The following is my attempt, however I fell very unsafe about the part circled red. I figured out it has to be this way, but I don't have a clear understanding why the circled part holds rigorously (intuitively it holds). Anyone can help with my confusion? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think the crucial fact is to understand the definition above - why $\tau_A(X_0 = x, X_1, X_2, \ldots) = 1 + \tau_A(X_1, X_2, \ldots)$ if $x \notin A$. If you understand this, then the circled step is just following from this definition, and law of total expectation.

Comment: @BGM Hi, thank you for your reply. I think I understand the identity at least intuitively, but I don't clearly see how to derive the equation of expectation. If possible, can you help explain about the " law of total expectation" part in your comment? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe just notational issue? Applying law of total expectation: $\mathbb{E}[\tau_A(X_0 = x, X_1, X_2, \ldots)|X_0 = x] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[\tau_A(X_1, X_2, \ldots)|X_0 = x] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\tau_A(X_1, X_2, \ldots)|X_1]|X_0 = x]$